# WPF - Binding grid width on load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Grid in data template looks like this:

```
<ListView Name="lvJobs" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="7" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#DDB20C" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" Padding="10">
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=gContainer, Path=ColumnDefinitions[1].Width.Value, Converter={StaticResource JobsWidthConverter}}">
```

Grid width bounded to parent grid:

```
<Grid Margin="3" Name="gContainer">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

When I change column width by moving GridSplitter, nested grid resize. However when program just started nested grid width didn't same parent column width.
How can I set correct nested grid width when program just started?

P.S. JobWidthConverter is simple:

```
class JobsWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double d = (double) value;
        return d - 80;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your grid Width to ActualWidth instead of Path=ColumnDefinitions[1].Width.Value

Comment: It works on start application, however nested grid don't resize when I move GridSplitter

Comment: ColumnDefinitions[1] is supposed to be the gridsplitter one?